# checking status of individual node of cluster created with parallel::makeCluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Let's say I've created a cluster using: `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)` and I send a call to the first node using `parallel:::sendCall(cl[[1]], f, arg)`.

I want to get the results of a specific node (in this case the first node). I can do that using `parallel:::recvResult(cl[[1]])`. However, this process blocks until a result is received. Is there any way to check the status of of a specific node? I.e. a status like "is processing" or "is finished".

Comment: `try({setTimeLimit(1,1, T); parallel:::recvResult(cl[[1]])}` seems to work,  but does not feel _clean_...

Comment: How are you sending the tasks to the cluster workers? Are you using `sendData`?

Comment: I'm using `sendCall` for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the standard `socketSelect` function. For example:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3, outfile="")

# Send task to worker 1
x <- 2
parallel:::sendCall(cl[[1]], sqrt, list(x), tag=1)

# Wait up to 5 seconds for worker 1 to send the result back
ready <- socketSelect(list(cl[[1]]$con), timeout=5)

if (ready > 0) {
    result <- parallel:::recvData(cl[[1]])
    cat(sprintf("sqrt(%f) = %f\n", x, result$value))
} else {
    cat("result not ready after five seconds\n")
}
```

See the source for the `recvOneData.SOCKcluster` function in the file snowSOCK.R for a more complete example.